# is `CompletableFuture.completedFuture ... thenAccept` equivalent to sequential processing?

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm working on a project with a lot of `CompletableFuture.completedFuture ... thenAccept` codes, e.g.

```
    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> callee() {
        boolean result = ... // Do something and get result - Step A
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.valueOf(result));
    }

    public void caller() {
        callee().thenAccept(result -> {
            // Detect if call success or failure - Step B
            new Throwable().printStackTrace(); // the debug code: stacktrace shows it is called from caller
        });
    }
```

I concluded that Step A and Step B are called sequentially in one thread.

So can I simplify it like this?

```
    public boolean callee() {
        boolean result = ... // Do something and get result
        return result;
    }

    public void caller() {
        boolean result = callee();
        // Detect if call success or failure
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can simplify it like this. The long version:

I think the question should be rather: "Is this usage of `CompletableFuture` appropriate?". No, it's not. This code is using `CompletableFuture` like a wrapper, a package, to pass data around and not as a tool to execute code asynchronously. This tool *can* be used to pass data around between threads, but it's not what this code is doing.

Calling `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` does nothing but create a new `CompletableFuture` that is completed with whatever you pass to the method. Then you call `thenAccept` on it, which has basically the following effect: "Take the result when it's done and let the thread that has calculated the result execute the following code. If the result is already calculated, let the caller execute the following code themself." The "following code" is simply the lambda you pass to `thenAccept`.

The initial `CompletableFuture` is completed instantly and the following code gets executed by the thread that calls `thenAccept` directly. The thread that executes `caller` and `callee` does everything itself. So this part is effectively doing nothing asynchronously. Therefore, the code is *equivalent* to the simpler code in the second example without `CompletableFuture`.

To actually make use of `CompletableFuture`, you should run `boolean result = ... // Do something and get result - Step A` asynchronously by e.g. creating this initial future using [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)). The chained code will also be run asynchronously.